# AngularJS $compile not evaluating expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been stuck on something for some time now and need some help.  I'm trying to build a tab control that allows me to dynamically add tabs with HTML content.  The tab control that I found uses an id element to reference the url for the tab.  What' I've found is that I can hardcode the id with my tab name and it will work, but if I use an expression {{eisEvent.url}} the $compile will not evaluate this to the real name.  I would have put this in a fiddle, but JSFiddle is having some major problems today, so I'll paste the code instead.  It's just three files.

style.css

```
ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
li {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 border-bottom-width: 0;
 margin: 3px 3px 0px 3px;
 padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
 background-color: #CCC;
 color: #696969;
 }
#mainView {
border: 1px solid black;
clear: both;
padding: 0 1em;
}
.active {
background-color: #FFF;
color: #000;
}
```

tabs.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('TabsApp', []);

myApp.service('EISEventService', function($rootScope) {
   var eisSubscriptions = [];

   this.addSubscription = function( eisEvent ){
      console.log( eisEvent.name + "\n" + eisEvent.message );
      $rootScope.$broadcast( "EVENT_ADDED", eisEvent );
      eisSubscriptions.push( eisEvent );
   };

   this.removeSubscription = function( eisEvent ){
      //TODO Remove the element from the array.
      $rootScope.$broadcast( "EVENT_REMOVED", eisEvent );
   };
});

myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', function ($scope, EISEventService) {
   console.log("Initializing Tab Controller");
   $scope.eisEvent = {};
   $scope.tabs = [{
      title: 'One',
      url: 'one.tpl.html'
   }, {
      title: 'Two',
      url: 'two.tpl.html'
   }];

   $scope.currentTab = 'one.tpl.html';

   $scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
      $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
   };

   $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
      return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
   };

   $scope.$on('EVENT_ADDED', function( event, args ){
      console.log( "EventName : " + event.name );
      var eisEvent = args;
      console.log("EIS Event = " + eisEvent.name  );
      console.log("Message = " + eisEvent.message );
      console.log("URL = " + eisEvent.url );
      $scope.eisEvent = eisEvent;

      $scope.tabs.push( {title : eisEvent.name, url:eisEvent.url });
      // By doing this, it seems to work, but I need the second option to work because I will eventually retrieve this HTML from
      // the server that will need to be parsed.
      // Option 1
      $scope.tabs_html.push( {html: '<script type="text/ng-template" id="'+eisEvent.url+'">Hello Event: '+eisEvent.name+'</script>' });

      // Option 2
      //This doesn't appear to work because of the binding.
      //$scope.tabs_html.push( {html: '<script type="text/ng-template" id="{{eisEvent.url}}">Hello Event: {{eisEvent.url}}</script>' });

      // Option 3
      //If I hard code the ID it will work.  For example if I enter test in the text box on the demo, the code below will work.
      //$scope.tabs_html.push( {html: '<script type="text/ng-template" id="test_url">Hello Event: {{eisEvent.url}}</script>' });
   });
   $scope.tabs_html = [];
});

myApp.controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, EISEventService) {
   $scope.onAddClick = function(){
      console.log("add clicked");
      var eisEvent = { name : $scope.txtName, url: $scope.txtName+"_url", message: "This is a log message"};
      EISEventService.addSubscription(eisEvent);

   }
});
myApp.directive("bindCompiledHtml", function($compile, $timeout) {
   return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      scope: {
         rawHtml: '=bindCompiledHtml'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
         scope.$watch('rawHtml', function(value) {
            if (!value) return;
            // we want to use the scope OUTSIDE of this directive
            // (which itself is an isolate scope).
            var newElem = $compile(value)(scope.$parent);
            elem.contents().remove();
            elem.append(newElem);
         });
      }
   };
});
```

And Lastly tabs.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TabsApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!--<script src="../lib/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tabs.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
<div>
    <div id="add" ng-controller="AddCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="txtName">
        <button ng-click="onAddClick()">Add</button>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs" ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
                ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}"
                ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="mainView">
            <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="one.tpl.html">
            <div>
                <h1>View One</h1>
                <p>Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc.</p>
            </div>
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="two.tpl.html">
            <div>
                <h1>View Two</h1>
                <p>Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu.</p>
            </div>
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="three.tpl.html">
            <div>
                <h1>View Three</h1>
                <p>In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu.</p>
            </div>
        </script>
        <div>
            <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs_html" bind-compiled-html="tab.html"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can just run the app, type in some text and click the add button.  This will add a tab with the URL that's the same.  See the JavaScript comments in the JS file for Option 1, Option 2, and Option 3.  Currently Option 1 is uncommented to show that it works.  If you comment this out and uncomment Option 2, this is the option that I need to work but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Can you provide some Plunker/Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ji5Oc2lvV1umk4htVwK9?p=preview) for you

What if you $compile the html first, like this

```
  var htmlString = '<script type="text/ng-template" id="{{eisEvent.url}}">Hello Event: {{eisEvent.url}}</script>';
  var htmlElement = $compile(htmlString)($scope);
  $scope.tabs_html.push( {html: htmlElement });
```

You must of course inject the compile service

```
myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', function ($scope, EISEventService, $compile) {
```

Comment: Outstanding!! Just what I needed.

Comment: I just found a bug with this as I put the solution into my application.  Add two tabs with two different names (e.g. test1, test2).  The content of the tab doesn't change accordingly.  I'm currently trying to figure out why.

Comment: Looks like the $scope.tabs_html.push is referencing the uncompiled variable {{eisEvent.url}} which is setting the same value each time.  So basically every item in the tabs_html is the same.